# Create DropDownListFor using strings from a List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I feel this should be simple but haven't found a guide on here that explains the use of dropdownlistfor in MVC.

I have a simple List of Names in a method in a class Users:

```
public List<string> getUsersFullNames()
    {
        return (from da in db.Dat_Account
                join ra in db.Ref_Account on da.AccountID equals ra.AccountID
                select ra.FirstName + " " + ra.Surname).ToList();
    }
```

I want to display each of these names in a dropdownlist so that a name can be selected.

I tried to get this working but have had no success.

My controller:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult ManageUserAccounts()
    {
            ViewBag.UserList = oUsers.getUsersFullNames();
            return View();
    }
```

My Model:

```
public class ManageUserAccountsViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Users")]
    public List<SelectListItem> UserList { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserList, new SelectList(oUsers.getUsersFullNames(), "Select User"));
```

I'm quite new to asp.net MVC as I have always used webforms in the past. Has anyone any idea if this is possible or a way to display this?

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to `List<SelectListItem>`. Your model needs a simple property to bind to (the value of the selected option), e.g. `public string SelectedUser { get; set; }`

Comment: Could you give me an example? I tried something similar to this earlier with no luck. Thanks

Comment: Travis Schettler's edit is now correct, except that I suggest that `public List<string> UserList { get; set; }` be `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserList { get; set; }` and you use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, Model.UserList, "Select User")` and the `[Display]` attribute needs to be on `User`, not `UserList`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help

Comment: Then you should consider accepting Travis' answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend using the model directly in the view, instead of the ViewBag. Update your action to include a model reference:

```c#
public ActionResult ManageUserAccounts()
{
    var model = new ManageUserAccountsViewModel();
    model.UserList = oUsers.getUsersFullNames();
    return View(model);
}
```

Your model should be updated to include a selected User property:

```c#
public class ManageUserAccountsViewModel
{
    public string User { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Users")]
    public List<string> UserList { get; set; }
}
```

Your view should be binding to the model:

```razor
@model ManageUserAccountsViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, new SelectList(Model.UserList), "Select User")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried this but still get the same result, the list of names builds fine but nothing is displayed in the view.

Comment: Updated with a more complete answer.